# Is this translation correct in simple present tense?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I want to say "I usually eat bread" in Korea, so I translate that sentence like this: "저는 자주 빵을 막는다". I wonder if the tense of my translated sentence is "present simple" and if that translated sentence has the same meaning with the English sentence

Answer (score 1):

The tense is correct.  먹는다 (not 막는다) is in the present simple tense.

You can make these improvements to make it more accurate and natural.

- 자주 is more like "frequently" or "often".  보통 is the common word for "usually".
- -는다 is a sentence ending form used more in writing.  In adult conversation, 먹어요 is better.
- 나는 is what's called a plain form without a polite feel.  Saying 저는 is more polite.

So you can say: 저는 보통 빵을 먹어요, where -어요 is a polite sounding sentence ending in the present simple tense.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tony's answer, you normally can't say "저는... 먹는다": "저" is a polite way to say "I," so it must pair with a polite verb ending such as "먹어요" or "먹습니다."  Similarly, "나" normally pairs with 먹어/먹는다/etc.

If you're talking to a friend, you could say "나는 보통 빵을 먹어."  If you're writing a diary or a novel, you may use a more formal expression: "나는 보통 빵을 먹는다."

- Sometimes people do say "나는 보통 빵을 먹어요" (which would be semi-polite) although some people consider that bad style (because of mismatched politeness level).